# Setting a value to 0 in maths if it is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

In meteor I'm fetching data from a mongodb database, the data is something like

```
{
"a": {
    "value": 1
},
"b": {
    "value": 1
},
"c": {

}
}
```

I need to add the values of "value" from all these results. However in c it is undefined, in some cases it is defined and in others it isn't. Is there a way to set the value of this to 0 or a method of achieving this using mongodb query syntax.

so

```
var sum = a.value + b.value c.value
```

c.value is undefined by needs to be treated as 0.
"c" can be any name and this trend is for at least through a-d with multiple fields being undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sum = (obj.a && a.value || 0) + (obj.b && b.value || 0) + (obj.c && c.value || 0);
```

Or if you want to iterate over and sum all fields of a data object:

```
var sum = 0;

for (var i in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[i].value === "number") {
        sum += obj[i].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: alternatively `var sum = ~~a.value + ~~b.value + ~~c.value;`

Comment: Sometimes these will be nested further e.g. b.value.of may be undefined this leads to a typerror when reading an undefined parent.

Comment: @user-33324 please provide an example as a part of your question

Comment: @Dymyto `{ "a": {value: 1}, "b": {value: 3}}` but I still need to add c.value even if c is undefined.

Comment: @user-33324 I have modified my answer. You can use either of the approaches I have listed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the curiosities with this db structure are a pain

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another (longer) method, you could check the property exists within the loop:

```js
var obj = {
  "a": {
    "value": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "value": 1
  },
  "c": {

  }
};

var val = 0;

for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('value')) {
    val += obj[i].value;
  }
};

console.log(val); // 2
```

Answer (score -2):

Before you use the values can't you just check if the values is falsy/undefined?

```
var jsonResult = // Ajax request to fetch json.
if (!jsonResult.c) 
{ 
    jsonResult.c = 0 
}
```